# how to get value x without code duplication

Tags: sql

```
    create table t(a int, b int);
    insert into t values (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3);

    select * from t;

    a   |   b
    ----------
    1   |   1
    1   |   2
    1   |   3
    2   |   1
    2   |   2
    2   |   3
    3   |   1
    3   |   2
    3   |   3

    select
      max(case when a = 1 then b else 0 end) as q,
      max(case when b = 1 then a else 0 end) as c,
      (
        max(case when a = 1 then b else 0 end)
        +
        max(case when b = 1 then a else 0 end)
      ) as x
    from t
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
    select
      max(case when a = 1 then b else 0 end) as q,
      max(case when b = 1 then a else 0 end) as c,
      (q + c) as x
    from t
```

Comment: 1) The answer may vary based on your SQL vendor. MySQL? Oracle? SQL Server? 2) I bet a temp table holding the first two columns, then a select from it to select the two columns plus the new column, could do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use the `ALIAS` that was given on the same level of the `SELECT` clause.

You have two choices:

- by using the expression directly

query:

```
select
  max(case when a = 1 then b else 0 end) as q,
  max(case when b = 1 then a else 0 end) as c,
  (max(case when a = 1 then b else 0 end) + max(case when b = 1 then a else 0 end)) as x
from t
```

- by wrapping in a subquery

query:

```
SELECT  q, 
        c,
        q + c as x
FROM
(
  select
      max(case when a = 1 then b else 0 end) as q,
      max(case when b = 1 then a else 0 end) as c
    from t
) d
```

Comment: TNX 100x! subquery is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Also in SQLServer2005+ you can use CTE

```
;WITH cte AS
 (
  select max(case when a = 1 then b else 0 end) as q,
         max(case when b = 1 then a else 0 end) as c
  from t
  )
  SELECT q, c, q + c as x
  FROM cte
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that unfortunately.

The ALIAS can not be used in the same level where you created them.

A temporary table is necessary, i think.